# Woocommerce add class foreach cart item if it has certain attribute term (This works but i can't figure out to make it cleaner, any thoughts?)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class', 10, 3 );
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class( $brand, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$terms1 = 40; $terms2 = 38; $terms3 = 43; $terms4 = 35; $terms5 = 42; $terms6 = 41; $terms7 = 44; $terms8 = 37; $terms9 = 45; $terms10 = 39; $terms11 = 36;


      if ( has_term( $terms1, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $brand = 'brand-1  cart_item';
    } elseif  ( has_term( $terms2, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-2  cart_item';
      } elseif  ( has_term( $terms3, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-3  cart_item';
      } elseif  ( has_term( $terms4, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-4  cart_item';
      } elseif  ( has_term( $terms5, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-5 cart_item';
      } elseif  ( has_term( $terms6, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-6  cart_item';
      } elseif  ( has_term( $terms7, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-7 cart_item';
      } elseif  ( has_term( $terms8, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-8  cart_item';
      } elseif  ( has_term( $terms9, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-9  cart_item';
      } elseif  ( has_term( $terms10, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-10  cart_item';
      } elseif  ( has_term( $terms11, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $brand = 'brand-11  cart_item';
      }


    return $brand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class( $brand, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    $terms = array( 40, 38, 43, 35, 42, 41, 44, 37, 45, 39, 36  );

    foreach ( $terms  as $key => $term ) {
        if ( has_term( $term, 'pa_brand', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $brand = 'brand-'.$key.' cart_item';    
            break;
        }
    }

    return $brand;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class', 10, 3 );
```